# pnpm ERR_PNPM_SYMLINK_FAILED error on windows machine

Tags: package-managers, npm-package, pnpm

Whenever I try to install any package in any project, I get this error that says `ERR_PNPM_SYMLINK_FAILED`
I get this error when I use `pnpm` to install package. The command I used is `pnpm i express`.

I get this error in a particular drive in my pc(letter D) But, in other drives, it works fine.
The full error message is like below:

```bash
/d/server $ pnpm i express
Packages: +62
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 ERR_PNPM_SYMLINK_FAILED  Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, symlink 'D:\server\node_modules\.pnpm\accepts@1.3.8\node_modules\accepts\' -> 'D:\server\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\nodmodules\.pnpm\accepts@1.3.8\node_modules\accepts\' -> 'D:\server\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\node_modules\accepts'
Progress: resolved 62, reused 0, downloaded 62, added 19
/d/server $
```

I'm using windows 10 pro here.
This is a new installation of windows, I used to use Linux mint as my daily driver. When I switched to windows 10, I get this error. I tried removing the old `.pnpm-store` directory from the drive. But all in vain.

What's wrong with this drive or with pnpm?

I want to fix the issue and want to continue developing in windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a slightly similar error but mine was an error involving renaming some node_module file when I ran `pnpm install` after doing a `pnpm create next-app`. If you run this in the same directory do you get similar issues?

If so, the issue is likely that the D: drive was formatted as EXFAT and the file's structure or linking wasn't working.
You can attempt an install on an NTFS-formatted drive or C:. For me: Other options I considered trying was running in elevated commands (I use `scoop install sudo & sudo pnpm install`) [or run it in WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install)